# Can you make the Xamarin iOS UIAlertController actionsheet into a multiselect?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I've been tasked with adding a feature to an existing app that would allow the user to select multiple items. I don't have much experience working with native iOS apps, but we use this UIAlertController quite a bit. It seems like it should be possible to convert this control into a multiselect, but even if it's not possible, I just need any easy way to allow the user to select multiple items and then hit an OK button. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

UIAlertViewController do not have multi choice function.I suggest you can add a tableview on a UIAlertViewController.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use UIAlertController with action sheet style for your custom list. https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIAlertController/